# Unable to execute bash scripts from heat template

Tags: openstack-heat

I am new to heat templates and I am trying to run bash scripts from  the heat template. However, the instance is coming up in active state but the shell script was not executed at all. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful for you.

```
parameters:   DBRootPassword:
    type: string
    label: Database Password
    description: Root password for MySQL
    hidden: true

resources:   my_instance:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      # general properties ...
      user_data:
        str_replace:
          template: |
            #!/bin/bash
            echo "Hello world"
            echo "Setting MySQL root password"
            mysqladmin -u root password $db_rootpassword
            # do more things ...
          params:
            $db_rootpassword: { get_param: DBRootPassword }
```